# How to convert a Response from string to jsonObject?

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, katalon-studio

My response as below and I want to convert it to json object but I don't know how to do it. Could you guide me? Thank you!
Response:

```
{"m_list": "[{\"contract\":{\"category\":1,\"cor_num\":101,\"contract_name\":\"ABC\"},\"bu_unit\":{\"bu_name\":\"1-1E\"}}]"}
```

My expected => It'll convert as a json object as below

```
{ m_list: 
   [ { contract: 
        { category: 1,
          cor_num: 101,
          contract_name: 'ABC'},
       bu_unit: { bu_name: '1-1E' }} ] }
```

I tried the following way but seem it didn't work

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str)

Comment: That's an invalid JSON response, it's an object without the surrounding `{` and `}`. The value it contains is a JSON array encoded as a String, which is fine, but an odd thing to do. You should talk to whoever is providing that response and ask them what they are doing.

Comment: I see that you've edited the JSON string and added the `{` and `}`. Do you still have a problem? The error message you have given is not consistent with that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use library *Josson* to restore the JSON object/array from a string inside a JSON.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{\"m_list\": \"[{\\\"contract\\\":{\\\"category\\\":1,\\\"cor_num\\\":101,\\\"contract_name\\\":\\\"ABC\\\"},\\\"bu_unit\\\":{\\\"bu_name\\\":\\\"1-1E\\\"}}]\"}");
```

**Transformation**

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("map(m_list.json())");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "m_list" : [ {
    "contract" : {
      "category" : 1,
      "cor_num" : 101,
      "contract_name" : "ABC"
    },
    "bu_unit" : {
      "bu_name" : "1-1E"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Also, May I ask you an additional question? After outputting the above json object => How to write the above json object into a file? 
The above is only an short example of my json object => Actually, my json object are very long. I tried doing the following but a file is written with the inside content does not fully

Josson jossonExpected = Josson.fromJsonString(str)
file = new FileWriter('D:\\AutoTest\\TaraNG\\Data Files')
file.write(jossonExpected.toJsonString(jossonExpected))

Comment: Do you mean that there are entries other than `m_list` in the root object? If so, use function `field()` instead of `map()`. -> `field(m_list.json())`

Comment: This solution produces a _Jackson_ `JsonNode` object. You can convert the `JsonNode` to `String` by `node.toString()`. e.g. `file.write(node.toString());`

Comment: I tried the way you recommended => But the file still isn't written fully (my original response are total 200 items but the file written only ~ 170 items => So it's not a valid json file ) => Do you know the reason why?

Comment: I resolved this problem above. But I've faced the following problem => Could you help me?
When running API and return a Response in string format like this: {"m_list": "[{\"contract\":{\"... <= only One "\" character => It seems that It needs to convert to "{\"m_list\": \"[{\\\"contract\\\":.... <== Three "\\\" characters => just use can use library Josson to restore the JSON object, right? How to convert from "\" to "\\\"? Could you help me? (Sorry because I've just learned code)

Comment: You don't need to convert it. Just use `Josson.fromJsonString(yourResponseStringVariable);`. You see \\\" in the string literal because it is how Java to escape special character when hard coding string literal.

Comment: The problem's resolved. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The string you want to convert is not in the JSON format. From the official documentation of JSON https://www.json.org/json-en.html - it has to start with left brace { , and end with right brace }.

Following the comment from @tgdavies if you get the response from some server, ask for clarification. If you just do this yourself, then this string is the correct format for the json file you want.

```
{"m_list":[{"contract":{"category":1,"cor_num":101,"contract_name":"ABC"},"bu_unit":{"bu_name":"1-1E"}}]}
```